# Passing variables received in GET string through a php header redirect?

Tags: php

I tried passing variables through a redirect and it comes up empty on the other side. Does anyone know what the problem could be? I tried searching for solutions here and could not find it:

```
header("Location: https://photorankr.com/instagram_fancybox/index.php?code=".$token."&id=".$userid);
```

on my other file I then get the variable as such:

```
$codedown = htmlentities($_GET['code']);
```

Nothing is shown up in the url and nothing is echoed.

Comment: the corresponding url is just this: https://photorankr.com/instagram_fancybox/index.php?code=&id=

Comment: not sure i understand your problem. In the redirected page, the variable `$codedown` is empty ?

Comment: From your URL, it seems `$token` and `$id` are not set in the first script. We can get a better idea if you include code that sets them.

Comment: @gillyb yes that is correct. You can see from above that nothing is passed in the url. I tried hard-coding the variables $token and $id as follows and still nothing:
$token = "10";
$userid = "100";

Comment: It should work, probably you have a problem with the `$token` and `$userid` variables before even sending them in the Location header...

Comment: @hw  $token = "10"; $userid = "100";

Comment: @gillyb I guess your right. I'm have a large function where I define these variables and nothing is passed through unless I define the variables below the function. How can I get the variables from my function passed through? I call this function where token and userid are retrieved.  $httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost($clientid, $clientsecret, $codedown, $granttype, $redirecturi, $endpoint);

Comment: the code only works if I define the variables below the function.

Comment: well, then obviously you have a problem in the function. This means you have a different problem, and should just post another question, and close this one.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to print the token and userid in the same page. The code you wrote above is correct, and try to get the variable on other page as $_REQUEST['code'] and $_REQUEST['id']